# Find Value of $g'(0)$ if $g(x)$ is inverse of $f(x)$, where $f(x)=\int_{2}^{x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1+t^4)}}dt$.

Tags: definite-integrals

> Find Value of $g'(0)$ if $g(x)$ is inverse of $f(x)$ where $$f(x)=\int_{2}^{x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1+t^4)}}dt.$$

I had tried following things

- finding $f(x)$ by integration but failed
- is $g(x)$ is inverse of $f(x)$ then $$fog = x$$
  So $$f'(g(x)) = \frac{1}{g'(x)}$$ and differentiate $f(x)$ by applying **Newton - Leibniz** and get 
  $$g'(x) = {\sqrt{1+{g(x)}^{4}}}$$
  And after putting $$ x = 0$$
  I get
  $$g'(0) = {\sqrt{1+{g(0)}^{4}}}$$

But still I need to find $$g(0)$$ 
And I have no clue how to find that

Comment: @zahbaz sorry it's a mistake I am correcting it .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $g= f^{-1}$, then when $f(x)=0$, $g(0)=x$. We can solve for it then using

$$0=\int_{2}^{g(0)}\frac{1}{{(1+t^4)}^{1/2}}dt$$

No need to integrate. What must $g(0)$ be?

> $g(0)=2$. The integrand is positive, so the interval of integration must vanish.

Comment: Thanks buddy for helping me

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: Would it be when the function being integrated has $t=g(0)$ and this is equal to when $t=2$?

Comment: @HenryLee Yes, though for clarity, I'd use a variable other than $t$, since that's the integration variable. See spoiler box in edit for solution.